# Embedding content in a panel ctools plugin- any other options

Tags: chaos-tool-suite, database

instead of using views, on some occasions, I want to write custom code to display a list of content. I know how to create ctools content type plugins, and in here I could create my EntityFieldQuery to display my content and allow it to be embedded. I was wondering if there are any other options for making my custom code available for embedding in a panel other than creating a ctools content type plugin as mentioned. Ctools content type plugin feel a little  verbose for for the task...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I definitely understand your problem with a ctools pane feeling verbose.

Unfortunately I don't have a great fix. I tend to copy an old content type to a new one and edit names and such.

What you make not know is that the normal `single => TRUE` property of a content type can be switched to `FALSE` allowing the code to create multiple panes in a single content type. (Actually I think `FALSE` is the default, so you don't even need to).

This allows you to share a lot more code between several panes that act similarly.

Another, simpler but more limited option is [Fieldable panels panes](https://drupal.org/project/fieldable_panels_panes), which basically allows you to take an entity, put fields on it, and stick it directly into a variant. If your needs are simply to display simple content, that could be enough, but this isn't enough when more complex logic is needed.

Actually a pane that requires a `EntityFieldQuery` context as an argument and then basically just themes it would be very interesting. There's probably use for at least a sandbox that provided the context and content type for that. :)

I'll try to write up more details if necessary, but look at `plugins/content_types/custom/custom.inc` for an example of a content type that does the above.

Someone may also have taken the time to write a drush command to generate a content type from a template. Haven't looked around for one though.

Comment: This all sounds very interesting. Any further details would be welcomed.

Comment: I added a short comment with another option, but haven't really expanded the existing information. I don't currently have the time to write a really good answer, so if you can specify what you need help with, that'd make it more likely I can improve the answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use blocks. You can start from [here](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.api.php/function/hook_block_info/7).

Comment: Being a big Ctools fan, I strongly disagree. When someone has taken the time to improve their code quality with panes instead of blocks, (providing some level of inversion of control), _please_ don't suggest to them that they should go back to blocks. Blocks are essentially becomes ctools panes in D8 for a reason.

Comment: I know but it was the easiest way to go. Thanks your comment enlightens more on this.